# Cannot catch MongoConnectionException

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am getting MongoConnectionException on trying to connect to mongodb server, when mongod is not running. Unfortunately, I am unable to catch the exception. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the following code?

```
try {
    $conn = new \Mongo('localhost');
    self::$mdb = $conn->filestore;
} catch(MongoConnectionException $e) {
    trigger_error('Mongodb not available', E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

The above code fails with the Exception

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with
>   message 'Invalid argument'

I tried to catch the exception using MongoConnectionException and Exception classes, but both are not working.

Comment: Have you tried just MongoException?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're using \Mongo I suspect you're in a namespace. Because of that, you need to catch on \MongoConnectionException (or \Exception).